# Length list, calculate odds

Tags: python

```
import math
a = int(raw_input('Enter Average:')) # Average number probability
c = int(raw_input('Enter first number:')) #
d = int(raw_input('Enter last number:')) #
e = 2.71828
for b in range(c,d+1):
    x = (a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(e**-a)
    odd = round (1/x*0.92, 2)
    print odd

For expected number of points in the range from-to, it calculates how much the odds for   each correct number of points.
```

Example : if expected number of points 200 , what is the odd for range 189-192?
I calulated odds for every number in range 189,190,191,192. (43.17,41.0,39.16,37.59)
how to calculate finall odds?

```
x = 41.0/(41.0/43.17+41.0/39.16+41.0/37.59+1) = **10.03**
```

But i dont know how to calculate for a list in advance the length of.

Comment: do you want to caluclate the average for all the numbers in range?

Comment: no , want to calculate for all odds that i have final odds with math formula x = b/(b/a+b/c+b/d...+1). i want to calculate X in example, to get result 10.03 :))) Odds (posibility) for some range of points, relative to average.

Comment: but what your using as b is the one of the range value please change variables so that we can understand what you want.since your math b is the odd of 190 i think!

Comment: Note that the `math` module has the e constant built-in, `math.e`. But you rarely need it, as it also has an efficient version of the exponential function `math.exp()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, add all your odds to a list and then

pseudo code:

```
sum = 1;

for odds in theListOfOdds
    sum += (b/odds)

result = b/sum
```

Comment: try to explain through example:
in some handball match  expected number of goals is 50 , what is the odds for range 47-48 goals? i calculate odds for exactly 47 goals (17.36) and 48 goals (16.74) and odds for range of goals are 16.74/(16.74/17.36+1) = 8.52. dont know that second step how to input. ")

Comment: you don't need more input, since you already have the numbers

Comment: sorry no input, i need to create another loop, but how?

Comment: initiate a new list and then do ''theListOfOdds.append(odd)'' in the first loop, and then iterate over that list in the second loop as my suggestion.